# php messagelistener for activemq

Tags: php, activemq-classic, message-queue, stomp, messagebroker

I am currently using stomp to send and receive/consume messages in activemq queues, but the stomp consumer is working synchronously , meaning the stomp consumer keeps checking if there is any new messages in the queue .But what I need to do is to make activemq notify my stomp consumer when a new message enters the queue . like the Onmessage() method in Java for example . I searched for days but still no luck . 
my current php code ( how I read messages from queue using stomp) :

```
while (true) {

       $frame = $stomp->readFrame();
       if ($frame != NULL) {
           print "Received: " . $frame->body . " - time now is " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"). "\n";
           $stomp->ack($frame);
       }
       else {
       print "No frames to read\n";
   }
```

Comment: That is going to be a feature of you php STOMP client, so please let people know what you are using.

Comment: well any working solution for any php,stomp versions will be just fine, i can update the versions if needed.

Comment: https://github.com/reactphp/stomp seems to support what you want but that seems to only supports STOMP 1.0

Comment: thank you @Buchi . github.com/reactphp/stomp , worked it is asynchronous and have alot of good features .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem .

used github.com/reactphp/stomp library and it worked perfectly . 
it consumes messages from my message broker asynchronously now .

Answer (score 0):

I've checked reactphp/stomp library and looks great. I think that the messages are read either way, but I like the event-driven sense that the scheduled timer adds to the application design. In my opinion, just go with it.
For all other people not interested in using yet another new library but still worried about the overhead of an infinite loop checking every CPU tick, here are 2 options to explore:
- Adding a sleep($timeout) before next check (end of each iteration)
- Using the Event class distributed as PECL extension (not bundled with PHP)